How to make 3 stage pipeline for a 16 points FFT to shorten the critical path delay to (multiplier) +(adder)

If I try to make a 16-point radix-2 FFT like this image, how can I shorten its delay +, where  is the propagation delay of a multiplier and  is the propagation delay of an adder, just by 3 stage pipeline? For a 16-point FFT, there are 4 groups of butterfly operations, and each group (e.g., stage 1) already includes an adder and a multiplier, so the delay becomes +. Based on this, I would need a 4-stage pipeline to achieve the desired performance, not a 3-stage pipeline.
Are there alternative architectures for calculating a 16-point FFT? Or is there another approach I can take to reduce the critical path delay to Tm+Ta with only a 3-stage pipeline?

Heads up, there is a dedicated DSP site at [dsp.se]. You might get a better answer over there.
